# Solidity hex literal on variable

Tags: solidity

In solidity, I can take advantage of the hex literal in order to get back the corresponding hex value of a string, in the following way:

```
hex"001122FF"
```

I am wondering how to apply such literal on a variable. Let's say my hex string is a constant `hexValue`.

How can I apply the literal on `hexValue`?

Thanks for the help

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, can you write some code to explain the idea?

Comment: Consider a variable string memory value = "001122FF". How can I apply the hex literal on the variable value?